# Why do Laravel relationships prevent calls to query builder methods?

Tags: php, orm, laravel-4, eloquent

I want to find all patients that belong to a user where `id = 1`

This works:

```
$data = Patient::where('user_id', '=', 1)
        ->with('method', 'images')->get()->toJson();
```

This doesn't work:

```
$data = User::find(1)->patients->with('method', 'images')->get()->toJson();
```

It says:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::with()
```

Why is it wrong? Could it be corrected?

Comment: Try `User::find(1)->patients()->with('method', 'images')->get()->toJson();` - does that work?

Comment: oh.. just a sec! Yup it works. :) Could you make that into an answer so I could upvote it properly? I never had to use () with relationships before.

Comment: cool - I've posted my comment as an answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is all Eloquent relationship declaration returns different result depending on whether you are trying to access the relationship as property or as method (with `()` or **without** `()`).

```
// Return you chainable queries    
$query = User::find(1)->patients()->... 
// Return you collection of patients
$patientsCollection = User::find(1)->patients;
```

Comment: And a collection is not chainable. It is not an object you can use with query builder methods cause it's not an instance of Query/Builder? I get it. interesting.

Comment: They basically returns different types. You are right though, you can't chain queries if you use `User::find(1)->patients` because at that time, the query has been executed (Eloquent will retrieve all patients for user with ID = 1), thus not chainable. However you can start using Eloquent collection methods (e.g. `User::find(1)->patients->toArray()`)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
User::find(1)->patients()->with('method', 'images')->get()->toJson();
```

Comment: Try to explain what is the () doing?

Comment: It is basically returning the patients model itself, allowing you to chain further actions on, rather than the patient result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$patient = New Patient;
$data = $patient->where('user_id','=',1)->with('method','images')->get()->toJson();
```